# jquery - add a class to random sets of divs with infinite loop

Tags: jquery, loops, random

i have the next html code

```
<div class="item item1"></div>
<div class="item item2"></div>
<div class="item item3"></div>
...
<div class="item item40"></div>
```

i want to choose random array of divs to add an active class to them for that i use this jquery code

```
function randOrder() {
    return ( Math.round(Math.random())-0.5 ); 
} 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items = [ 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9', 'item10', 'item11', 'item12', 'item13', 'item14', 'item15', 'item16', ... , 'item40' ];
    var randitems = items.sort( randOrder ).slice(0,5);
});
```

now i want to set an interval to the `randitems` to choose a random of classes to add "active" class to them .
but how i can make a loop for that , i want to choose rando divs with active class every 1000ms without refreshing of page

Comment: if @adeneo's demo isn't what you want ( it works for me also in 2 browsers) then it is not clear what you do want

Comment: wow sorry man the problem that the @adeneo's demo not working to me couse from my isp that blocked https protocol sorry adeneo and tnx for your perfect answer please re post it to check it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer from the @adeneo tnx @adeneo

```js
function randOrder() {
    return ( Math.round(Math.random())-0.5 ); 
} 

setInterval(function() {
    $('.item').removeClass('active').sort( randOrder ).slice(0,5).addClass('active')
}, 1000);
```

```css
.active {color: red};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
<div class="item">10</div>
<div class="item">11</div>
<div class="item">12</div>
<div class="item">13</div>
<div class="item">14</div>
<div class="item">15</div>
<div class="item">16</div>
<div class="item">17</div>
<div class="item">18</div>
<div class="item">19</div>
<div class="item">20</div>
<div class="item">21</div>
<div class="item">22</div>
<div class="item">23</div>
<div class="item">24</div>
<div class="item">25</div>
<div class="item">26</div>
<div class="item">27</div>
<div class="item">28</div>
<div class="item">29</div>
<div class="item">30</div>
<div class="item">31</div>
<div class="item">32</div>
<div class="item">33</div>
<div class="item">34</div>
<div class="item">35</div>
<div class="item">36</div>
<div class="item">37</div>
<div class="item">38</div>
<div class="item">39</div>
<div class="item">40</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cdxkxuw6/